# Archimedean property of rational numbers

Tags: real-analysis

The set of natural numbers is unbounded. can we prove this by using archimedean property?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange! A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).  For equations, please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 1):

Suppose there is a greatest natural number $N$.

The Archimedean property says that for every $x,y\in\mathbb R$ ($x,y>0$) there exists a $n\in\mathbb N$ so that $nx>y$. Now choose $x:=N$. Then, for $y:=N^2$, there exists a $n$ so that $$nN>N^2.$$ This is only possible for $n>N$, which is a contradiction.

It would be *way* easier however to just use Peano's axioms, where this is a direct implication.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, we can show that set of natural numbers is not bounded using Archimedean property.
The proof is simple,
We want:- if x belongs to R, then there exists n belonging to N such that x≤n.
Start with contradiction , then n≤x for n belonging to N . Therefore x is an upperbound of N .let u be the supremum of N . now u-1 is also a natural number which is not the upper bound hence there exists m such that u-1≤m which gives u≤m+1 which clearly tells that u is not an upper Bound. Hence contradiction. And there exists n belonging to N such that x≤n for all x belonging to R

Comment: [Welcome to Math.SE!](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4928/290189) Please use MathJax. For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/290189), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559/259305) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773/290189).